# Why IEEE table is pushed outside of the margins of the paper?

Tags: tables, ieeetran

I am finishing up a table for an IEEE publication but I have a **problem** because the table is pushed outside of the margins of the paper as you see below:

[image]

I am not sure why that is happening. Although I noticed that the "keyword" column might be the item responsible for this behavior because if some of the keywords are composed of a small word, than this problem is less visible (but still present). Also the second problem, very likely caused by the length of the "keyword" column, is that this causes a misalignment of the headers to the right but they should be in the middle.

Below is what I have obtained so far:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{siunitx}    % v3!
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}%
                     \hsize=#1\hsize}X}


% Other paragraphs...


\begin{table*}\centering
\ra{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{@{}rrrrcrrrcrrr@{}}\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{QUERY-1} & \phantom{abc}& \multicolumn{3}{c}{QUERY-2} &
\phantom{abc} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{QUERY-3}\\
\cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{6-8} \cmidrule{10-12}
& Keyword & Occurrence & Strength && Keyword & Occurrence & Strength && Keyword & Occurrence & Strength\\ \midrule
$Top$\\
$1.$ & photoacoustics & 58 & 1047 && photoacoustics & 854 & 23329 && -1.0032 & -1.7104 & -21.7969\\
$2,$ & ultrasonics & 59 & 712 && photo-acoustic imaging & 1063 & 19283 && 4.3590& 34.5809& 76.9167\\
$3.$ & photo-acoustic imaging & 50 & 615 && animals & 568 & 18569 && -121.0518& -137.1210& -220.2500\\
$4.$ & echography & 31 & 611 && human & 556 & 16810 && -121.0518& -137.1210& -220.2500\\
$5.$ & ultrasonic applications & 63 & 600 && mouse & 389 & 13542 && -1.2998& -3.8202& -1.2784\\
$6.$ & procedures & 23 & 552 && procedures & 421 & 13287 && -11.1631& -5.7108& -15.6728\\
$7.$ & ultrasound & 26 & 505 && diagnostic imaging & 350 & 10806 && 52.5745& 10.1098& -140.2130\\
$8.$ & diagnostic imaging & 23 & 460 && chemistry & 286 & 10113 && 52.5745& 10.1098& -140.2130\\
$9.$ & ultrasound imaging & 29 & 430 && female & 250 & 8782 && 52.5745& 10.1098& -140.2130\\
$10.$ & animal experiment & 15 & 417 && animal model & 204 & 7883 && 52.5745& 10.1098& -140.2130\\
$Bottom$\\
$1.$ & non-contact & 8 & 62 && photonics & 15 & 200 && -1.0032 & -1.7104 & -21.7969\\
$2,$ & surface defects & 8 & 62 && cardiovascular system & 7 & 199 && 4.3590& 34.5809& 76.9167\\
$3.$ & fiber reinforced plastic & 6 & 61 && ultrasonography & 6 & 199 && -121.0518& -137.1210& -220.2500\\
$4.$ & damage visualization & 5 & 58 && focused ultrasound & 12 & 197 && -121.0518& -137.1210& -220.2500\\
$5.$ & elastography & 5 & 57 && raman scattering & 9 & 196 && -1.0032 & -1.7104 & -21.7969\\
$6,$ & high spacial resolution & 6 & 56 && prostate cancer & 8 & 195 && 4.3590& 34.5809& 76.9167\\
$7.$ & computerized tomography & 8 & 54 && photoacoustic measurements & 13 & 94 && -121.0518& -137.1210& -220.2500\\
$8.$ & ultrasound propagation & 6 & 53 && excitation wavelength & 13 & 193 && -121.0518& -137.1210& -220.2500\\
$9.$ & laser ultrasonic systems & 6 & 51 && breast imaging & 9 & 190 && 4.3590& 34.5809& 76.9167\\
$10.$ & nondestructive testing & 7 & 49 && fluences & 10 & 1894 && -121.0518& -137.1210& -220.2500\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
\end{table*}
```

I have researched this problem quite a bit and came across [this source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264069/placement-of-table-in-ieee-paper), [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229871/trouble-creating-latex-table-ieee-paper) other source. They both were useful to have an understanding of the margins but still they could not be used to solve the issue I have.

I dug more into the problem and find out [this source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/583618/table-in-ieee-paper-format) and also [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/600434/changes-package-deleted-command-pushed-outside-margin). However, despite useful, those last two sources were not able to lead me to a proper conclusion.

Please if anyone had the same problem, point out to a proper solution.

**EDITS**

Thanks to a user the third column is updated to "words" values. However this is causing an incorrect behavior of the column as you can see below.

```
\begin{table*}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
     l lS[table-format=2.0] S[table-format=4.0]
       lS[table-format=4.0] S[table-format=5.0]
       *{3}{S[table-format=-3.4]} }
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{QUERY 1} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{QUERY 2} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{QUERY 3 (???)} \\
\cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{5-7} \cmidrule{8-10}
& Keyword & {\#} & {Strength} 
& Keyword & {\#} & {Strength}
& {Keyword} & {\#} & {Strength} \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\itshape Top}\\
1. & photoacoustics & 58 & 1047 & photoacoustics & 854 & 23329 & human & 803 & 18692 \\
2. & ultrasonics & 59 & 712 & photo-acoustic imaging & 1063 & 19283  & three dimensional imaging & 606 & 15014 \\
3. & photo-acoustic imaging & 50 & 615 & animals & 568 & 18569 & female & 544 & 13097 \\
4. & echography & 31 & 611 & human & 556 & 16810 & echography & 492 & 12084 \\
5. & ultrasonic applications & 63 & 600 & mouse & 389 & 13542 & ultrasonopgraphy & 271 & 6733\\
6. & procedures & 23 & 552 & procedures & 421 & 13287 & ultrasonics &  289 & 5390 \\
7. & ultrasound & 26 & 505 & diagnostic imaging & 350 & 10806 & pregnancy & 207 & 5075 \\
8. & diagnostic imaging & 23 & 460 & chemistry & 286 & 10113 & algorithms  & 187 & 5039 \\
9. & ultrasound imaging & 29 & 430 & female & 250 & 8782 & 3d ultrasound & 227 & 4569 \\
10. & animal experiment & 15 & 417 & animal model & 204 & 7883 & fetus echography & 150 & 3645 \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\itshape Bottom}\\
1. & non-contact & 8 & 62 & photonics & 15 & 200 & cancer prognosis & 5 & 107 \\
2. & surface defects & 8 & 62 & cardiovascular system & 7 & 199 & image resolution & 9 & 106 \\
3. & fiber reinforced plastic & 6 & 61 & ultrasonography & 6 & 199 & wave propagation & 7 & 105 \\
4. & damage visualization & 5 & 58 & focused ultrasound & 12 & 197 & position sensors & 5 & 104 \\
5. & elastography & 5 & 57 & raman scattering & 9 & 196 & fibers & 6 & 103 \\
6, & high spacial resolution & 6 & 56 & prostate cancer & 8 & 195 & medical robotics & 7 & 103 \\
7. & computerized tomography & 8 & 54 & photoacoustic measurements & 13 & 94 & breast lesion & 5 & 101 \\
8. & ultrasound propagation & 6 & 53 & excitation wavelength & 13 & 193 & segmentation methods & 7 & 100 \\
9. & laser ultrasonic systems & 6 & 51 & breast imaging & 9 & 190 & robotic surgery & 6 & 99 \\
10. & nondestructive testing & 7 & 49 & fluences & 10 & 1894 & transducer elements & 6 & 98 \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Caption}
\end{table*}
```

[image]

Comment: Your table is wider than the available text width. You should get a warning about this (Overfull \hbox (75.00496pt). For an overview of approaches you could use to make your table fit, you may want to take a look at [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/134144)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two different suggestions on how you could make sure your table fits into the available space:

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{siunitx}    % v3!
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}

\begin{document}


\begin{table*}
\caption{Caption}
\centering
\ra{1.3}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4.75pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{}r l S[table-format=2] S[table-format=4] 
                     lS[table-format=4] S[table-format=5]
                     l S[table-format=3]S[table-format=5]@{}}\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{QUERY-1} &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{QUERY-2} &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{QUERY-3}\\
\cmidrule(r){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7} \cmidrule(l){8-10}
& Keyword & {Occur.} & {Strength} & Keyword & {Occur.} & {Strength} & {Keyword} & {Occur.} & {Strength}\\ \midrule
\multicolumn{10}{@{}l}{\itshape Top}\\
1. & photoacoustics & 58 & 1047 & photoacoustics & 854 & 23329 & human & 803 & 18692 \\
2. & ultrasonics & 59 & 712 & photo-acoustic imaging & 1063 & 19283  & three dimensional imaging & 606 & 15014 \\
3. & photo-acoustic imaging & 50 & 615 & animals & 568 & 18569 & female & 544 & 13097 \\
4. & echography & 31 & 611 & human & 556 & 16810 & echography & 492 & 12084 \\
5. & ultrasonic applications & 63 & 600 & mouse & 389 & 13542 & ultrasonopgraphy & 271 & 6733\\
6. & procedures & 23 & 552 & procedures & 421 & 13287 & ultrasonics &  289 & 5390 \\
7. & ultrasound & 26 & 505 & diagnostic imaging & 350 & 10806 & pregnancy & 207 & 5075 \\
8. & diagnostic imaging & 23 & 460 & chemistry & 286 & 10113 & algorithms  & 187 & 5039 \\
9. & ultrasound imaging & 29 & 430 & female & 250 & 8782 & 3d ultrasound & 227 & 4569 \\
10. & animal experiment & 15 & 417 & animal model & 204 & 7883 & fetus echography & 150 & 3645 \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{10}{@{}l}{\itshape Bottom}\\
1. & non-contact & 8 & 62 & photonics & 15 & 200 & cancer prognosis & 5 & 107 \\
2. & surface defects & 8 & 62 & cardiovascular system & 7 & 199 & image resolution & 9 & 106 \\
3. & fiber reinforced plastic & 6 & 61 & ultrasonography & 6 & 199 & wave propagation & 7 & 105 \\
4. & damage visualization & 5 & 58 & focused ultrasound & 12 & 197 & position sensors & 5 & 104 \\
5. & elastography & 5 & 57 & raman scattering & 9 & 196 & fibers & 6 & 103 \\
6, & high spacial resolution & 6 & 56 & prostate cancer & 8 & 195 & medical robotics & 7 & 103 \\
7. & computerized tomography & 8 & 54 & photoacoustic measurements & 13 & 94 & breast lesion & 5 & 101 \\
8. & ultrasound propagation & 6 & 53 & excitation wavelength & 13 & 193 & segmentation methods & 7 & 100 \\
9. & laser ultrasonic systems & 6 & 51 & breast imaging & 9 & 190 & robotic surgery & 6 & 99 \\
10. & nondestructive testing & 7 & 49 & fluences & 10 & 1894 & transducer elements & 6 & 98 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\newpage


\begin{table*}
\caption{Caption}
\ra{1.3}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}r >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X S[table-format=2] S[table-format=4] 
                     >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}XS[table-format=4] S[table-format=5]
                     >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X S[table-format=3]S[table-format=5]@{}}\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{QUERY-1} &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{QUERY-2} &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{QUERY-3}\\
\cmidrule(r){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7} \cmidrule(l){8-10}
& Keyword & {Occur.} & {Strength} & Keyword & {Occur.} & {Strength} & {Keyword} & {Occur.} & {Strength}\\ \midrule
\multicolumn{10}{@{}l}{\itshape Top}\\
1. & photoacoustics & 58 & 1047 & photoacoustics & 854 & 23329 & human & 803 & 18692 \\
2. & ultrasonics & 59 & 712 & photo-acoustic imaging & 1063 & 19283  & three dimensional imaging & 606 & 15014 \\
3. & photo-acoustic imaging & 50 & 615 & animals & 568 & 18569 & female & 544 & 13097 \\
4. & echography & 31 & 611 & human & 556 & 16810 & echography & 492 & 12084 \\
5. & ultrasonic applications & 63 & 600 & mouse & 389 & 13542 & ultrasonopgraphy & 271 & 6733\\
6. & procedures & 23 & 552 & procedures & 421 & 13287 & ultrasonics &  289 & 5390 \\
7. & ultrasound & 26 & 505 & diagnostic imaging & 350 & 10806 & pregnancy & 207 & 5075 \\
8. & diagnostic imaging & 23 & 460 & chemistry & 286 & 10113 & algorithms  & 187 & 5039 \\
9. & ultrasound imaging & 29 & 430 & female & 250 & 8782 & 3d ultrasound & 227 & 4569 \\
10. & animal experiment & 15 & 417 & animal model & 204 & 7883 & fetus echography & 150 & 3645 \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{10}{@{}l}{\itshape Bottom}\\
1. & non-contact & 8 & 62 & photonics & 15 & 200 & cancer prognosis & 5 & 107 \\
2. & surface defects & 8 & 62 & cardiovascular system & 7 & 199 & image resolution & 9 & 106 \\
3. & fiber reinforced plastic & 6 & 61 & ultrasonography & 6 & 199 & wave propagation & 7 & 105 \\
4. & damage visualization & 5 & 58 & focused ultrasound & 12 & 197 & position sensors & 5 & 104 \\
5. & elastography & 5 & 57 & raman scattering & 9 & 196 & fibers & 6 & 103 \\
6, & high spacial resolution & 6 & 56 & prostate cancer & 8 & 195 & medical robotics & 7 & 103 \\
7. & computerized tomography & 8 & 54 & photoacoustic measurements & 13 & 94 & breast lesion & 5 & 101 \\
8. & ultrasound propagation & 6 & 53 & excitation wavelength & 13 & 193 & segmentation methods & 7 & 100 \\
9. & laser ultrasonic systems & 6 & 51 & breast imaging & 9 & 190 & robotic surgery & 6 & 99 \\
10. & nondestructive testing & 7 & 49 & fluences & 10 & 1894 & transducer elements & 6 & 98 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you very much for taking the time to answer to my question I appreciate it a lot. Everything is great until another user made me notice a strange 3 QUERY column, which I erroneously took from another table (I just have to slap myself for this silly mistake). I added **EDITS** to the question showing the correct table.

Comment: I am extremely sorry for the confusion and please let me know if I should write another question. I think that this could be considered an annex to the question though. Also some cells  require automatic line wrapping as the words (some of them are long). Again sorry for the confusion and thanks in advance you could find a minute to edit your answer. I appreciate it!

Comment: @Emanuele Hint: You can also say "thanks for taking the time" by upvoting an answer.

Comment: @Emanuele: I just updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Since none of the cells appear to require automatic line wrapping, I suggest you employ a `tabular*` environment and set its overall width to `\textwidth`. I'd also suggest getting rid of all-blank columns. Oh, and since the `IEEEtran` class is generally quite particular about the appearance of captions (e.g., line break between caption number and caption text), I wouldn't clobber these class settings by loading the `caption` package.

Oh, the third query seems to be entirely different from the other two. No idea what's going on there.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
%\usepackage{caption} 
   % it's not a good idea to use the 'caption' package with the IEEEtran class
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
     l lS[table-format=2.0] S[table-format=4.0]
       lS[table-format=4.0] S[table-format=5.0]
       *{3}{S[table-format=-3.4]} }
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{QUERY 1} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{QUERY 2} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{QUERY 3 (???)} \\
\cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{5-7} \cmidrule{8-10}
& Keyword & {\#} & {Strength} 
& Keyword & {\#} & {Strength}
& {Keyword} & {\#} & {Strength} \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\itshape Top}\\
1. & photoacoustics & 58 & 1047 & photoacoustics & 854 & 23329 & -1.0032 & -1.7104 & -21.7969\\
2. & ultrasonics & 59 & 712 & photo-acoustic imaging & 1063 & 19283 & 4.3590& 34.5809& 76.9167\\
3. & photo-acoustic imaging & 50 & 615 & animals & 568 & 18569 & -121.0518& -137.1210& -220.2500\\
4. & echography & 31 & 611 & human & 556 & 16810 & -121.0518& -137.1210& -220.2500\\
5. & ultrasonic applications & 63 & 600 & mouse & 389 & 13542 & -1.2998& -3.8202& -1.2784\\
6. & procedures & 23 & 552 & procedures & 421 & 13287 & -11.1631& -5.7108& -15.6728\\
7. & ultrasound & 26 & 505 & diagnostic imaging & 350 & 10806 & 52.5745& 10.1098& -140.2130\\
8. & diagnostic imaging & 23 & 460 & chemistry & 286 & 10113 & 52.5745& 10.1098& -140.2130\\
9. & ultrasound imaging & 29 & 430 & female & 250 & 8782 & 52.5745& 10.1098& -140.2130\\
10. & animal experiment & 15 & 417 & animal model & 204 & 7883 & 52.5745& 10.1098& -140.2130\\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\itshape Bottom}\\
1. & non-contact & 8 & 62 & photonics & 15 & 200 & -1.0032 & -1.7104 & -21.7969\\
2. & surface defects & 8 & 62 & cardiovascular system & 7 & 199 & 4.3590& 34.5809& 76.9167\\
3. & fiber reinforced plastic & 6 & 61 & ultrasonography & 6 & 199 & -121.0518& -137.1210& -220.2500\\
4. & damage visualization & 5 & 58 & focused ultrasound & 12 & 197 & -121.0518& -137.1210& -220.2500\\
5. & elastography & 5 & 57 & raman scattering & 9 & 196 & -1.0032 & -1.7104 & -21.7969\\
6, & high spacial resolution & 6 & 56 & prostate cancer & 8 & 195 & 4.3590& 34.5809& 76.9167\\
7. & computerized tomography & 8 & 54 & photoacoustic measurements & 13 & 94 & -121.0518& -137.1210& -220.2500\\
8. & ultrasound propagation & 6 & 53 & excitation wavelength & 13 & 193 & -121.0518& -137.1210& -220.2500\\
9. & laser ultrasonic systems & 6 & 51 & breast imaging & 9 & 190 & 4.3590& 34.5809& 76.9167\\
10. & nondestructive testing & 7 & 49 & fluences & 10 & 1894 & -121.0518& -137.1210& -220.2500\\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Caption}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up comments/edits: I see that you've modified the material under "Query 3" considerably. That's great. All you need to do, really, is to change the column formats from `*{3}{S[table-format=-3.4]}` (which was appropriate for the earlier version) to `l S[table-format=3.0] S[table-format=5.0]`.

Optionally, consider shortening the longish string `three dimensional imaging` to `3d imaging`; this will make the text column less wide, allowing more whitespace to be inserted between all columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
%\usepackage{caption} 
    % it's not a good idea to use the 'caption' package with the IEEEtran class
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document} 

\begin{table*}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out the required amount of intercolumn whitespace
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
     l l S[table-format=2.0] S[table-format=4.0]
       l S[table-format=4.0] S[table-format=5.0]
       l S[table-format=3.0] S[table-format=5.0] }
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{QUERY 1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{QUERY 2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{QUERY 3} \\
\cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{5-7} \cmidrule{8-10}
& Keyword & {\#} & {Strength} & Keyword & {\#} & {Strength} & Keyword & {\#} & {Strength} \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\itshape Top}\\
1. & photoacoustics & 58 & 1047 & photoacoustics & 854 & 23329 & human & 803 & 18692 \\
2. & ultrasonics & 59 & 712 & photo-acoustic imaging & 1063 & 19283 & 3d imaging & 606 & 15014 \\
3. & photo-acoustic imaging & 50 & 615 & animals & 568 & 18569 & female & 544 & 13097 \\
4. & echography & 31 & 611 & human & 556 & 16810 & echography & 492 & 12084 \\
5. & ultrasonic applications & 63 & 600 & mouse & 389 & 13542 & ultrasonopgraphy & 271 & 6733\\
6. & procedures & 23 & 552 & procedures & 421 & 13287 & ultrasonics & 289 & 5390 \\
7. & ultrasound & 26 & 505 & diagnostic imaging & 350 & 10806 & pregnancy & 207 & 5075 \\
8. & diagnostic imaging & 23 & 460 & chemistry & 286 & 10113 & algorithms & 187 & 5039 \\
9. & ultrasound imaging & 29 & 430 & female & 250 & 8782 & 3d ultrasound & 227 & 4569 \\
10.& animal experiment & 15 & 417 & animal model & 204 & 7883 & fetus echography & 150 & 3645 \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\itshape Bottom}\\
1. & non-contact & 8 & 62 & photonics & 15 & 200 & cancer prognosis & 5 & 107 \\
2. & surface defects & 8 & 62 & cardiovascular system & 7 & 199 & image resolution & 9 & 106 \\
3. & fiber reinforced plastic & 6 & 61 & ultrasonography & 6 & 199 & wave propagation & 7 & 105 \\
4. & damage visualization & 5 & 58 & focused ultrasound & 12 & 197 & position sensors & 5 & 104 \\
5. & elastography & 5 & 57 & raman scattering & 9 & 196 & fibers & 6 & 103 \\
6, & high spacial resolution & 6 & 56 & prostate cancer & 8 & 195 & medical robotics & 7 & 103 \\
7. & computerized tomography & 8 & 54 & photoacoustic measurements & 13 & 94 & breast lesion & 5 & 101 \\
8. & ultrasound propagation & 6 & 53 & excitation wavelength & 13 & 193 & segmentation methods & 7 & 100 \\
9. & laser ultrasonic systems & 6 & 51 & breast imaging & 9 & 190 & robotic surgery & 6 & 99 \\
10.& nondestructive testing & 7 & 49 & fluences & 10 & 1894 & transducer elements & 6 & 98 \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Caption}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you very much for taking the time and effort to answer. Everything is great until I noticed that thanks to you I have a strange 3 QUERY, which I erroneously took from another table (I just have to slap myself for this silly mistake). After updating with the correct values the result is [this one](https://i.imgur.com/RF9sUIm.png). Which is very strange because it pushes all the words in a very wrong place. I added **EDITS** to the question.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and please let me know if I should write another question or if this could be considered an integration to the question. Also to answer to your clarification, some cells appear require automatic line wrapping as the words (some of them are long).

Comment: @Emanuele - Please see the addendum I posted below my original answer. Basically, all one has to adjust is the columns specifications for the 3 columns under "Query 3".